# Steps to deploy a Site Definition having a custom Master page

Tags: 2007, development, master-page, site, site-definition

we have custom site definition with a custom master page, I copied it from Control Templates, made changes to "ONET.XML" and master page they are using. I also renamed site definition folder name and the Master page file name , Now **I can't figure out what steps do I have to follow to install/deploy this site definition and master Page.** btw I am using sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change masterPage name and then you need to find and replace master page from ONET.xml file as well, which is in XML folder in site definition.

Put the Site Definition folder in 12 hive and make a WEBTEMP.. file and put it in XML folder in 12 hive directory as well.

what WEBTEMP.. file does is, it shows your template in the options when you try to create a site/workspace.

Hope it helped others

Answer (score 0):

Did you package it as a solution?

Comment: nope, its just a folder with master page and then another folder of XML with  ONET.xml in it

Comment: I copied the folder to the Control Template, made a new WEBTEMP for it, now if i create it it says invalid template, gonna see if i did something wrong some where